# When transferring live agent chat, the auto greeting repeats and is inaccurate

Tags: liveagent, automation

We have over 100 deployments of Live Agent. One for each of our company brands and locations. The auto greeting for each is specific for the brand & location.
Example: Hello! Thanks for chatting with us at MyBusiness Unit of Salt Lake City. My name is {!User_FirstName}.How can we help you today?

When a customer starts the chat with a location then the agent determines they are not who the customer needs to be speaking with and transfers the chat to the correct agent, the original message repeats with the same values as before, even though the agent and location/business unit no longer apply. This leads to customer confusion.

How can we have a greeting and ensure the greeting is correct even through transfers? I'm open to a configuration or coding solution.

Salesforce has confirmed there is no configuration option to address this and pointed me to go vote for an idea already posted.

Steps to Reporoduce:
Start a live agent chat session from one of our web pages, say MyBusiness Unit of Atlanta 
You receive greeting like: Hello! Thanks for chatting with us at My Business Unit of Atlanta My name is John.How can we help you today? 
Ask the agent a question about MyOther Business Unit Web Page  The MyBuiness Unit agent will indicate they must transfer you to a different agent (call center) 
Chat is transferred, you will receive same greeting: Hello! Thanks for chatting with us at My Business Unit of Atlanta My name is John.How can we help you today? 
but should have got a greeting like Hello! Thanks for chatting with us at My Other Business Unit. My name is Jill. How can we help you today?

During the transfer the Agent Name and Location will both be changed, but the message is the same.

This leads to customer confusion and agent frustration. Any ideas?

Here is a link to the SF Idea referenced by Support:
[Live Agent - Auto Response for transfers](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0XCAAY)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a link to the idea you reference...It may also help to include your code/configuration.

Comment: A comment on the idea links to the "service cloud cookbook" which does appear to have a sample tailored at this issue.  Have you tried that?  https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/service_dev.pdf

Comment: Thank you @gorav for pointing this out.  I posted this before reviewing the link in detail based upon the agent comments. The sample code is generic and does not show how to use the new agent name, but this is better than we have and closer to answering the request.

Answer (score 2):

@gorav pointed out the link in my question to the service cloud cookbook.
deep in the cookbook there was a suggestion to use a custom component in the Service Cloud Console.
I have not tried this but it should work, or at least improve the messaging to reduce the customer and agent concerns.

The solution requires creation of a visual force page, custom component, and adding the component to the SC console.

John.

Apex Page:

```
    <apex:page>
 <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/32.0/integration.js"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        sforce.console.chat.onChatStarted(function(result) {
            sforce.console.chat.onAgentSend(result.chatKey,
            function(resOnAgentSend) {
                /*Monitors every chat message sent by the agent to verify
                that the chat has not been transferred.*/
                if(!(resOnAgentSend.isAutoGreeting && resOnAgentSend.isTransferred)) {
                    sforce.console.chat.sendMessage(result.chatKey,
                    resOnAgentSend.content, function(resSendMessage) {
                        if(!resSendMessage.success){
                            return;
} });
} else {
    /*Sends your customized transfer message to the customer
    if the chat has been transferred to a new agent. Replace
    the text in quotation marks to whatever you want your transfer
    message to say.*/
    sforce.console.chat.sendMessage(result.chatKey, "Hi! Thank you
    for your patience. Give me one second while I review your chat." ,
} });
} });
    });
</script>
</apex:page>
```